# Insert margin/padding between the slides on a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/72Hf2/

In this example `div#reference` is 500px wide... `div#carousel` expands to consume that.

The problem is there is no spacing between each `div.slide`. Adding any padding/margins to `div.slide` will break the carousel, therefore I have inserted a `div.thumbnail` inside of each `div.slide` and have applied my margin there, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/c34CF/1/

However that leaves a gap at the end. I must have no gap at the end.. however I can't simply use `:last-child` because the last visible slide is not the last element in the DOM. How can I achieve the spacing between slides without the gap issue?

From what I understand the best way would be applying a negative left/right margin on the `div#carousel` and then applying a positive left & right margin on each `div.slide`, which works in the jsFiddle but it screws up the actual carousel (The JS code assumes that `div#wrapper` is the exact sum of the widths of `div.slide`)... do I need to fork that carousel & change the way it works, or is there a workaround in CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the n-th child CSS selector as seen in http://jsfiddle.net/c34CF/6/

```
DIV:nth-child(6) > .thumbnail{

        margin-right:0 !important;
    }
```

However I guess, you might need something dynamic for your carousel of different sizes

If that is the case, try if following helps:

If you are using jQuery:
   $(".thumbnail > :nth-child(eqn)").css("margin-right", 0); //here "eqn" should be an expression which will help you access the last thumbnail index displayed in the carousel.

If you are not using jQuery, try using n-th child selector property using basic javascript.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. In my jsfiddle the slide containing the text "2" is in position 1. The slide containing "1" is in position -1 (not visible). Any `*-child` style selectors would no longer match the appropriate element once the user advances the carousel.

My concern with adding/removing classes with JS would be the elements "jump" around suddenly. There is a button that causes the carousel to advance 1 slide another that advances a page (5 slides), and the animations play out longer when advancing 5 slides... so adding/remove padding dynamically & not messing up these complex animations would be a feat

Comment: Ran out of comment space but I wanted to add this. I edited line 22 in your fiddle to simulate the user advancing a slide, to illustrate the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/c34CF/7/ you'll see there is now a gap because the styling is matching the wrong element. Its matching the element that was last, but no longer is last.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `:last-child`, you could use `:first-child` and swap the margin-right for margin-left

It would be something like this:

```
.thumbnail {
    border:1px red solid;
    margin-left:15px;
}

.slide:first-child .thumbnail {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

If you don't have to worry about IE7 or less, you can skip adding the `.thumbnail` altogther by setting the `box-sizing` property to `border-box`.

```
.slide {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;    /* not sure if the prefixes are still needed */
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.slide:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Box-sizing controls how margin and padding affect the width of an element. The default is `content-box` which works the way you are used to: an element has a width, lets say 100px and margin and padding extend off of that. So if you have 10px margin and 5px padding your width+margin+padding will equal 130.

When setting the property to `border-box`, the width **includes** margin and padding. So 100px width + 10px + 5px padding will have a total width of...100px! In other words, the margin and padding squish the content instead of pushing more space outwards. Chris Coyier as a [great article](http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/) and a [an example](http://css-tricks.com/examples/BoxSizing/) to see it in action.

**EDIT:** Fiddle using `:first-child`: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws4UQ/2/

Relevant code:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    width:1300px;
    margin-left:-115px; /* This is the width + margin of .slide */
}

.slide {
    width:100px;
    float:left;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox, other Gecko */
    box-sizing: border-box;    /* not sure if the prefixes are still needed */
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.slide:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

The margin just needs to taken into account when sliding the carousel (`#wrapper`). Instead of moving it by -100px, it will be -115px (the extra 15px is whatever you set the margin to). Just know that if you need it to work in IE8 you'll have to create a polyfill ([more info from Chris again](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/)).

Comment: Thanks for the response so far. When the user browses through the carousel, the slide in the left/right most positions will vary. See line 22 of the CSS in my first js fiddle. That's why slide "2" is the first slide visible in the carousel. `:first-child` would match slide "1" which is not in the 1st position, but is in position "-1" if you will.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/Ws4UQ/. You just need to account for the margin in the `margin-left: -YYYpx`. Instead of moving it by 100px, it will be 115px (the extra 15px is whatever you set the margin to). Just know that if you need it to work in IE8 you'll have to create a polyfill ([more info from Chris again](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-child/)). I'll adjust my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sorry, the fiddle I left in my comment has inccorect CSS (it's too late for me to edit it!). Please look at the new fiddle in my answer.

Comment: Thanks, that could work. I'd just need to modify the javascript to make it account for the 15px padding. Also your latest jsfiddle cuts off the last slide because border-box only includes padding & border, yet your 15px spacing is in the form of margins -  but It will work with padding on .slide and showing the border on .thumbnail. - I'll test more tomorrow & accept your answer if it works out.

Comment: Ah -you're right! I'll modify my answer for posterity. Let me know how it turns out.